# I'm getting error when I'm updating

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I'm getting error for 2 days. I'm getting error like below:

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1360 (packagekitd)

> N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.

> E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

I tried restarting packagekit service. But it didn'T work.

Comment: kill the process 1360 and try it again

Comment: Have you restarted your machine since the error first appeared? 

Comment: I restarted many times. It doesn't work when I first run. But it works after trying updating a few more times.

Comment: I tried to kill process 1360. It couldn't find process 1360. But it worked even though. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: This error is going on. But it doesn't display if I wait a few moments before updating. It displays when I'm updating it without waiting.